# Undefined property error in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I've just started with Node.js and I've created an endpoint that downloads images using the Bing API based on a given query.

I'm using the [node-bing-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bing-api)

```
app.get('/bing', function (req, res) {
    var query = req.query.q;

    buffer = {
        "response": [],
        "location": "",
        "count": 0
    };

    buffer.location = temp.tmpNameSync({
        template: 'XXXXXX'
    });

    Bing.images(query, {
        top: 10,
        imagefilters: {
            size: 'Medium'
        }
    }, parseResponse);

    function parseResponse(error, response, body) {
        async.each(body.d.results, deepParse, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Bing Async Error');
            } else {
                if (buffer.count > 0) {
                    async.each(buffer.response, downloadImages, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Image Download Async Error');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        res.send(buffer.location);
    }

    function downloadImages(data, callback) {

        var dir = 'images/' + buffer.location;
        var filename = dir + '/' + temp.tmpNameSync({
            template: 'XXXXXX.jpg'
        });

        mkdirp(dir, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Directory creation error');
            } else {
                request(data).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
                callback();
            }
        });
    }

    function deepParse(data, callback) {

        if (data.ContentType == "image/jpeg" && buffer.count < 5) {
            request.head(data.MediaUrl, function (err, result, body) {
                if (!err && result.statusCode == 200) {
                    buffer.response.push(data.MediaUrl);
                    buffer.count++;
                    callback();
                } else {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    }
});
```

The problem I'm facing is, Node throws an error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'd' of undefined
    at parseResponse (/Users/Primary/projects/node/librorum/server.js:335:18)
    at Request._callback (/Users/Primary/projects/node/librorum/node_modules/node-bing-api/lib/bing.js:104:7)
    at self.callback (/Users/Primary/projects/node/librorum/node_modules/request/request.js:354:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at null._onTimeout (/Users/Primary/projects/node/librorum/node_modules/request/request.js:961:12)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

I guess this happens at the first line of my parseResponse() function. I'm quite unsure what to do, as this error is sporadic. The code works at times and doesn't at other times ( even for the same query ).

My second question is, "If I run 3 different tabs with 3 different queries on /bing will there be 3 instances of app.get('/bing', func....) running, or just a single instance?"

The reason I'm asking is cause sometimes when I run multiple tabs on the same endpoint with different queries, some folders don't get created. And I'm not able to understand why. Probably because a new query comes in before the previous query completes ? ( probably this happens cause it's 3 queries from the same host ? )

Any solution would be immensely helpful !

Comment: Insert `console.log(body)` before `async.each` to see what you actually receive. Some requests probably fail, that's why you don't receive a body. It's might worth checking `response` status code.

Comment: @zaynetro alright I'm checking it now. Thanks !

Comment: @zaynetro I get an "undefined". Now is there any way to redo the entire app.get() for the same query ?

Comment: You should handle errors occuring with your Bing.images call, inside the callback `function parseResponse(error, response, body) { 
      if (error) throw (error)
      /* ... */`

Comment: @mef I've handled the error. Also I've just noticed that if I run 2 queries in quick succession, then all the images sit in just 1 folder and not 2 folders respectively.

For example,

query1 has to reside folder1 and q2 in f2. When I run q1 and q2 in quick succession, image results of q1 and q2 reside in f1. Sometimes q2 doesn't create a folder or download any images what so ever. Any suggestions on how to resolve this ?

Comment: @Dribba how about adding the updated code with error management in your question ?